# Creating a text input field precisely where a user clicks on a Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Right now I have a Google Map which places a mapLabel that says "Hello!" wherever a user clicks (and binds it to that Lat/Long)

This is done simply by

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeLabel(e.latLng, map);
});
```

and

```
function placeLabel(position, map) {
    var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
      text: 'Hello!',
      position: position,
      map: map,
      fontSize: 12,
      align: 'right'
    });
}
```

What I ultimately want is for the user to be prompted with a text dialogue so that they can have the text say whatever they want, however I am at a loss for how to accomplish this.

Any advice?

Comment: Where does `MapLabel` come from?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the functionality you currently have implements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. add an infowindow with a form at the point clicked

   ```
   var formStr = "<input type='text' id='text4mrkr' value='marker text' /><input type='button' value='submit' onclick='addPlace();' />"
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
       infowindow.setContent(formStr);
       infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
       infowindow.open(map);
   });
   ```
2. capture the data from the form and add (in this case) a marker with an infowindow containing that text.

   ```
   function addPlace() {
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map:map, position: infowindow.getPosition()});
       marker.htmlContent = document.getElementById('text4mrkr').value;
       infowindow.close();
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
           infowindow.setContent(this.htmlContent);
           infowindow.open(map,marker);
       });
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function() {
           this.setMap(null);
       });
   }
   ```

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var formStr = "<input type='text' id='text4mrkr' value='marker text' /><input type='button' value='submit' onclick='addPlace();' />"

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    infowindow.setContent(formStr);
    infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);

    // placeLabel(e.latLng, map);
  });
}

function addPlace() {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: infowindow.getPosition()
  });
  marker.htmlContent = document.getElementById('text4mrkr').value;
  infowindow.close();
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
    infowindow.setContent(this.htmlContent);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function() {
    this.setMap(null);
  });
}

function placeLabel(position, map) {
  var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
    text: 'Hello!',
    position: position,
    map: map,
    fontSize: 12,
    align: 'right'
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: This is amazingly slick, wish I could give you more than just a reputation!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer helped me as well. @geocodezip